# Importing Mapping variable from other smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to import mapping variable from some contract to another contract

my variable looks like :

> mapping(uint => uint256[]) public  endtime;

this is how i am accessing my contract:

> ```
> vault = MyNFTStorage(_vault);
> ```

I'm accessing my variabke like this:

> ```
> require(block.timestamp < vault.endtime[tokenId], "");
> ```

I am getting this error:

> ```
> > from solidity: TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping
> > or array (is function (uint256,uint256) view external returns
> > (uint256))   --> commerce.sol:53:35:    | 53 |        
> > require(block.timestamp < vault.endtime[tokenId], "");    |           
> > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access directly to the other Smart Contract's mapping.
You should create a view function in the first Smart Contract (where the mapping is), to access and retrieve different positions of the mapping (even a loop to return all positions, if your keys are incremental).

```
mapping(uint => uint256[]) public endtime;

function getMappingPosition(uint256 position) external view returns (uint256){
    return endtime[position];
}
```